# double parameter URL flask execute bash script

Tags: python, flask

How to write the flask approute to execute bash script if I have double parameters in the URL call? 
Here is my URL I am calling from browser
`http://0.0.0.0:5000/sample/fwd`
I was trying to write my flask approute like this.

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/<port>')
def get_shell_script_output_using_check_output(port):
    stdout = check_output(['./route.sh','-a',"{}".format(port)]).decode('utf-8')
    return stdout

@app.route('/<port>/<fwd>')
def get_shell_script_output_using_check_output(port,fwd):
    stdout = check_output(['./shadowSR.sh',"{}".format(port),"{}".format(fwd)]).decode('utf-8')
    return stdout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

But this is not working. Can any one suggest me how to mention the approute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
@app.route('/run/<port>/<fwd>')
def run(port, fwd):
    stdout = check_output(['./shadowSR.sh',"{}".format(port),"{}".format(fwd)]).decode('utf-8')
    return stdout
```